# SnackBar se muestra mas arriba de lo que necesito

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragment

Estoy teniendo un pequeño gran problema con un snackbar, resulta que cree uno personalizado siguiendome de unos tutoriales que encontre en internet, todo perfecto, hasta que se tiene que mostrar, les cuento un poco mas y voy al error.

Desde un boton creo y lanzo el 'SB', este boton se encuentra en un fragment y con esto lo lanzo

```
CustomSnackbar.make(getActivity().findViewById(R.id.v_principal),CustomSnackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Y asi se esta viendo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Se ve mucho mas arriba que mi TabLayout, y la idea es que se aparesca pegado..
Ahora estan viendo una transparencia por que yo le asigne eso, pero en realidad se muestra con un gris oscuro.

Esta es mi clase SB

```
public class CustomSnackbar extends BaseTransientBottomBar<CustomSnackbar> {

private CustomSnackbar(ViewGroup parent, View content, ContentViewCallback callback) {
    super(parent, content, callback);
}

public static CustomSnackbar make(@NonNull ViewGroup parent,  int duration) {
    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext());
    final View content = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_snackbar, parent, false);
    final ContentViewCallback viewCallback = new ContentViewCallback(content);
    final CustomSnackbar customSnackbar = new CustomSnackbar(parent, content, viewCallback);
    customSnackbar.getView().setPadding(0, 0, 0, 0);
    customSnackbar.getView().setBackgroundColor(parent.getContext().getResources().getColor( R.color.transparente));
    customSnackbar.setDuration(duration);
    return customSnackbar;
}


public CustomSnackbar setAction(CharSequence text, final View.OnClickListener listener) {
    Button actionView = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.snackbar_action);
    actionView.setText(text);
    actionView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            listener.onClick(view);
            // Now dismiss the Snackbar
            dismiss();
        }
    });
    return this;
}

private static class ContentViewCallback implements BaseTransientBottomBar.ContentViewCallback {

    private View content;

    public ContentViewCallback(View content) {
        this.content = content;
    }

    @Override
    public void animateContentIn(int delay, int duration) {
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 0f);
        ViewCompat.animate(content).scaleY(1f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay);
    }

    @Override
    public void animateContentOut(int delay, int duration) {
        ViewCompat.setScaleY(content, 1f);
        ViewCompat.animate(content).scaleY(0f).setDuration(duration).setStartDelay(delay);
    }
}
```

Porfavor, ya no se que hacer!, intente de todo

Gracias!

Comment: Donde aparezca: scaleY(1f) cambialo por: scaleY(0f) no estoy seguro por eso lo comento.

Comment: @denifersantiagofernandez Hola!, gracias por responder, pero lo quue me sugeriste no :c , ese scaleY toca la animacion, lo he probado y solamente ahora cuando se borra, se elimina directo sin animacion

Comment: Agrega el layout @LcsGrz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema tiene que ver con la libreria de google, el espacio blanco trasnparente del Snackbar es el alto de nuestros botones de navegacion, para correjirlo e echo lo siguiente:

**Obtengo el alto de la barra**

```
    public static void obtenerAltoNavbar(Context c) {
    Resources resources = c.getResources();
    int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier("navigation_bar_height", "dimen", "android");
    int id = resources.getIdentifier("config_showNavigationBar", "bool", "android");

    navBar = ((id > 0 && resources.getBoolean(id))) ? resources.getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId) : 0; 
// Guardo el alto de la barra de navegacion en una variable
}
```

**Luego, resto al margen inferion del snackbar la variable**

```
        FrameLayout.LayoutParams params = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) customSnackbar.getView().getLayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0 - **navBar**);
    params.gravity = Gravity.BOTTOM;
    customSnackbar.getView().setLayoutParams(params);
```

Y eso es todo! :D